# vba vlookup 11digit number not working

Tags: database, vba, vlookup

I've created an userform with some textbox, when the user populate the textbox with some part number (Ex: 160007) the other textbox all have vlookup formula to search in the database for some other informations.

The problem is, when vlookup searchs for partnumber that contains 1-9digits, it works perfet, but if there is a part number with more than 9 digits, if returns nothing (we have part number up to 15 digits, only numbers, no texts) I tried to change the database format to text, number, general... doesn't work

In the code below, the textbox3 is the problem when textbox2 is populate with big numbers

```
Private Sub TextBox1_AfterUpdate()


On Error Resume Next

'textbox2

Dim width, code
Dim WorkbookName As String
Dim WB As Workbook
Dim Sht As Worksheet
Dim Rng As Range


WorkbookName = "Bancodedados.xlsx"

' set the workbook object
On Error Resume Next
Set WB = Workbooks(WorkbookName) ' first try to see if the workbook already open
On Error GoTo 0
If WB Is Nothing Then ' if workbook = Nothing (workbook is closed)
    Set WB = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\arthurg\Documents\FERRAMENTAS\" & WorkbookName)
End If

' set the worksheet object
Set Sht = WB.Sheets("DMG850V")

' set the Range object
Set Rng = Sht.Range("A1:K20000")


' verify that Vlookup found code in the Range
On Error Resume Next
If Not IsError(Application.Vlookup(CLng(Me.TextBox1), Rng, 2, False)) Then
With Me
    TextBox2 = Application.Vlookup(CLng(Me.TextBox1), Rng, 2, False)
    End With

Else
    MsgBox "Ferramenta não encontrada" & ", entrar em contato com Engenharia"
End If

'textbox3

' set the workbook object
On Error Resume Next
Set WB = Workbooks(WorkbookName) ' first try to see if the workbook already open
On Error GoTo 0
If WB Is Nothing Then ' if workbook = Nothing (workbook is closed)
    Set WB = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\arthurg\Documents\FERRAMENTAS" & WorkbookName)
End If

' set the worksheet object
Set Sht = WB.Sheets("Descrição")

' set the Range object
Set Rng = Sht.Range("A:C")

' verify that Vlookup found code in the Range

On Error Resume Next
If Not IsError(Application.Vlookup(CLng(Me.TextBox2), Rng, 2, False)) Then
With Me
    TextBox3 = Application.Vlookup(CLng(Me.TextBox2), Rng, 2, False)
    End With

Else
    MsgBox "Ferramenta não encontrada" & ", entrar em contato com Engenharia"
End If
```

Comment: The problem, specifically, is that you are casting (For some reason) using `CLng` to a `Long` type. That can only hold numbers `-2147483648 to 2147483647`. You have a part number so treat it like a string since you aren't doing math with it. Just remove that `CLng` function so you can preserve the `Textbox1` value properly as a string.

Comment: Most of your `On Error Resume Next` can/should be removed: `Application.Vlookup` doesn't raise an error if there's no match.

Comment: Well, I tried it before, still not working, with the CLng I get no error message from the verify code, if I remove CLng then I get an error message that vlookup found nothing in the database, but it is there, I tried with a simple vlookup in a blank cell(out of my userform) and it worked

Comment: found a solution, changed to "VLookup(Val(Textbox1.Value)"

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer but too long for a comment.

This runs your lookup twice:

```
' verify that Vlookup found code in the Range
On Error Resume Next '<< not needed
If Not IsError(Application.Vlookup(CLng(Me.TextBox1), Rng, 2, False)) Then
With Me
    TextBox2 = Application.Vlookup(CLng(Me.TextBox1), Rng, 2, False)
    End With

Else
    MsgBox "Ferramenta não encontrada" & ", entrar em contato com Engenharia"
End If
```

This is cleaner:

```
Dim res
'no need for any error trapping here...
res = Application.Vlookup(CLng(Me.TextBox1), Rng, 2, False)
If Not IsError(res) Then
    Me.TextBox2 = res
Else
    MsgBox "Ferramenta não encontrada" & ", entrar em contato com Engenharia"
End If
```

Comment: Thank you, It didn't fixed the problem but it is way better now

Answer (score 0):

`CDbl()` worked for me

```
With Me
    ....
    .TextBox3 = Application.VLookup(CDbl(.TextBox2), rng, 2, False)
    ....
End With
```